# Is there an algorithmic way to check if a dataset oscillates?

Tags: algorithms, simulation, population

A simulation gives the population numbers for every species in the domain per frame. These vary over time and can be quite noisy, is there a way of analysing the data algorithmically without drawing a graph whether or not these values oscillate?

Comment: thanks, could you suggest any good resources to look at other than wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Run a Fourier transform (FFT) on every series. Look for frequencies that surpass a threshold.
Here is a tutorial for Matlab: http://www.ele.uri.edu/courses/ele436/labs/fft.pdf